# In Jetpack Compose, how can you make a new element always appear on the top of whatever content there is?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, android-jetpack-compose, state

I have two buttons, each one will make a text appear on the top of the screen content.

If I press Button A, then a text "Here is A" should appear at the top of the screen. If I press Button B, then a text "Here is B" should appear at the top of the screen.

If I press A and then B, then "Here is A" should appear first then "Here is B" should appear on top of that; the inverse should occur if I press B then A.

I've set it up as follows:

```
    val showA = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val showB = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
    if (showA.value) {
        Text(text = "Here is A!")
    }    
    
    if (showB.value) {
        Text(text = "Here is B!")
    }
    
    Button(onClick = { showA.value = true }) {
        Text(text = "Show A")
    }    
    
    Button(onClick = { showB.value = true }) {
        Text(text = "Show B")
    }
```

The issue here is: if I click A first, "Here is A!" appears, then if I click B after, "Here is B!" appears underneath it.

I want to be able to change this so that if I whatever I click second will always come above whatever I clicked first.

If I click Button A then Button B, I should see "Here is A!" followed by "Here is B!" on top of that. If I click Button B then Button a, I should see "Here is b!" followed by "Here is A!" on top of that.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You will see texts one over the other everytime when you press any button because on click of button, you are making one value true and not other value false, and since both values become true, it draws content over existing content.

In Compose, the order in which elements are declared in the code determines their stacking order on the screen. So, if you first set `showA.value` to true and then set `showB.value` to true, the text for B will be drawn after the text for A, appearing on top of it.

To fix this, you will have to make one value true and another value false:

```
    val showA = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val showB = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    
    if (showA.value) {
        Text(text = "Here is A!")
    }    
    
    if (showB.value) {
        Text(text = "Here is B!")
    }
    
    Button(onClick = { 
      showA.value = true 
      showB.value = false
    }) {
        Text(text = "Show A")
    }    
    
    Button(onClick = {  
      showA.value = false 
      showB.value = true
    }) {
        Text(text = "Show B")
    }
```

Or you can achieve it like this also:

```
enum class ButtonType {
    A, B
}

@Composable
fun ToggleVisibilityExample() {
    var activeButton by remember { mutableStateOf<ButtonType?>(null) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        activeButton?.let { buttonType ->
            Text(
                text = "Here is ${buttonType.name}!",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
            )
        }

        Button(onClick = { activeButton = ButtonType.A }) {
            Text(text = "Show A")
        }

        Button(onClick = { activeButton = ButtonType.B }) {
            Text(text = "Show B")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only replaces the text on top by either A or B. I want to have "Here is A!" and "Here is B!". If I click Button A then Button B, I should see "Here is A!" followed by "Here is B!" on top of that.  If I click Button B then Button a, I should see "Here is b!" followed by "Here is A!" on top of that.

Comment: Then you need to apply background color so that background content/ previous content is hidden due to background. According to your question, B is shown underneath - that is actually wrong because in Compose, new content is always drawn above previuous content.

Comment: Currently, when A is visible and you press Show B button, then B is drawn above A, its not underneath!